# 400 Bad Request in python web browser

Tags: python, sockets, server

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to open a .txt file from a website.

My code is :

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysocket.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysocket.close()
```

and I get the message :
Bad Request-Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

I can read the .txt file with urllib but I didn't get why it doesn't work in this way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The URI (the part of the HTTP command following "GET") should be relative to the server. If you change `cmd` to `'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'` you should find your code works. Please don't be concerned if this question gets closed - that simply indicate that answers are unlikely to add anything of value to the site content.

Comment: Thanks, but I get still the same error

Comment: cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()   Try \r\n \r\n instead of \n\n  The request/status line and headers must all end with <CR><LF> (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed).

Comment: see also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773601/getting-a-400-bad-request-error-using-socket-in-python-3?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a 400 Bad Request Error Using Socket in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773601/getting-a-400-bad-request-error-using-socket-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with \n\n in your request.

"The request/status line and headers must all end with CR LF (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed)."

You need to use \r\n

Change your line to this:

```
cmd = 'GET data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

Same answer here:
[Getting a 400 Bad Request Error Using Socket in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773601/getting-a-400-bad-request-error-using-socket-in-python-3?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use requests?

```py
# python -m pip install —user requests
import requests
r = requests.get('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')

print(r.text)
```

Or

```py
from urllib import request

r = request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
text = b''
for line in r:
    text+=line
print(text)
```

Finally a working socket

```py
import socket

uri = 'data.pr4e.org'
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((uri, 80))
    cmd = f'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {uri}\r\n\r\n'.encode()
    s.send(cmd)

    while True:
        data = s.recv(512)
        if (len(data)<1):
            break
        print(data.decode())
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it with also urllib, I just want to know where the problem is because it is an example from a python course

Comment: Oh, let me try using sockets

Comment: I added a socket example just for completeness